# limit inferior is the least cluster point of $\{ x_{n} \}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-explanation, limsup-and-liminf

Here is the proof of the statement on the title that has been given to me. I understand everything except the last line. Perhaps someone could enlighten me.

> Let $c'$ be a cluster point of $\{x_n\}$ and $c=\lim \inf x_n > c'$. Then there exists a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ of  $\{ x_{n} \}$ such that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} x_{n_k}=c'$.
>
> In other words, $\forall \ \epsilon>0, \ \exists \ N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ \forall \ k\geq N$ we have $\mid x_{n_k}-c'\mid <\epsilon$. 
> Choose $\epsilon = \frac{c-c'}{2}$. Then there are infinitely many $ x_{n_k}$ such that  $x_{n_k} \leq c'+\epsilon = c-\epsilon$. Hence $c=\lim \inf x_n=c-\epsilon$ which contradicts $c'<c$.

I do not understand how $c=c-\epsilon$ contradicts $c'<c$. The only contradiction I see is that $c=c-\epsilon$ is problematic since $\epsilon \neq 0$ but I do not see how this implies that $c$ has to be less than or equal to $c'$. What am I missing?

Comment: If a premise leads to a false conclusion (such as $ c= c - \epsilon$ where $\epsilon\neq 0$), then the premise must be false (by contradiction).

Comment: No, I understand that but I'm struggling to see how $c=c-\epsilon$ is actually a function of said premise.

Comment: In your second paragraph, should $c = \liminf x_n$?

Comment: @fwd absolutely, thank you.

Comment: You have quoted a sequence of statements that begins with “Let $c'$ be a cluster point of $\{x_n\}$ and $c' < c$” and ends with “$c = c - \epsilon$ where $\epsilon \neq 0$”.  *Where* do you lose the train of thought?

Comment: It has just occurred to me that we did indeed use $c'<c$ in order to ensure positivity of our choice of $\epsilon$ so the premise of $c'<c$ was **actually applied** in obtaining the contradictory statement. Silly mistake. Thanks all!